# [ReactJS][React-Router-V4] Redirects[auth] problems

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm setting up a new React JS project and i want to redirect peoples on authPage when peoples aren't connected.

I have a App container like that:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
return (
  <div className={'app-wrapper'}>
    <Helmet
      titleTemplate="FFMKR"
      defaultTitle="React.js Boilerplate"
    >
      <meta name="description" content="A React.js Boilerplate application" />
    </Helmet>
    <Header />
    <div className={'container-fluid'}>
      <div className={'row'}>
        <SideBar />
        <main role="main" className={'col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4'}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="" component={NotFoundPage} />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

and my PrivateRoute like that:

```
  const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  const { component: Component, isLogged, ...rest } = props;
  console.log('on est dans la route lol', isLogged, {...rest});

  return (
    <Route
  {...rest}
  render={propsRender =>
    isLogged ? (
      <Component {...propsRender} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/login",
          state: { from: propsRender.location }
        }}
      />
    )
  }
/>
);
};


PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  isLogged: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

My variable isLogged is already false. When i start my app i go on url "/" and i'm redirect on url"/login" but my Login component is not showed:

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/03/1/1547456719-capture-d-ecran-de-2019-01-14-10-04-38.png

When i reload on url "/login" my Login component work fine:

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/03/1/1547456719-capture-d-ecran-de-2019-01-14-10-04-58.png

Why i start my app, my login component not appear ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you must return the `Redirect` component and not render it. So, you have to do something like the below example

```
export class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    const { isLogged } = this.props;

    if (!isLogged()) {
      return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }

    return (
      <Route
        {...this.props}
        component={props => (
          <this.props.component
            {...props}
          />
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the url in the address bar changes to /login then react-router is working as expected. There might be something wrong with your Login component. Try replacing the Login component with something simple like the following and then test:

```
function Login() {
  return <h3>Test login page</h3>;
}
```

Comment: (sorry can't comment on your post as I do not have enough reputation points here, it seems I can only comment on my own answers)
As per what you have posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54182431/4979359 it seems your Login component has a bug, React state management could be a little tricky. Can you post the code of your Login component?

Answer (score 0):

Ho, sorry i don't show this informations in my screens, but the url address bar changes to /login, i have return this function, but i have the same problem.

That not works the first time but if i reload the page on url /login thats works and i have "Test login page" on screen.

I test PrivateRoute component when isLogged === true and thats works
I don't understand why my Login component is not displayed.